# Is it possible to use bindModel to bind 3 different nested tables in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a segment which can have many comments and each comment can have many tags. I can bind the comments to the segments using code like the below which is a function in the segment model class.

```
function prepareForGettingSegmentsWithComments() {
  $this->bindModel(
   array('hasMany' => array(
     'Comment' => array(
      'className' => 'Comment',
      'foreignKey'    => 'segmentID'

     )
    )
   )
  ); 
 }
```

However how can I bind in the Tags as well?

Comment: Isn't this just a Segment hasHamy Comment, Comment hasMany Tag.  Bind Comment to Segment, Tag to Comment.  Use containable for filtering on queries.  Am I missing something?

Comment: turned out the issue lay in the fact that segmentID was not segment_id (the database also had segmentID). I changed everything (models and database tables to the _id). It appears to be a bug in cake that the hasMany etc does not work with alternate foreign keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in this situation, I bind the Tags to the Comments with a belongsTo. Then filter the results with some query conditions.

Let me see if I can find an example snippet somewhere,

```
if(isset($this->params['named']['category'])){
  $this->Link->bindModel(
    array('belongsTo' => array(
          'CategoriesLink' => array(
              'className' => 'CategoriesLink',
              'foreignKey' => 'id',
          )
      )),
    array('belongsTo' => array(
          'Category' => array(
              'className' => 'Category',
              'foreignKey' => 'categories_link_id',
          )
      ))
  );

  $data = $this->paginate('Link', array('CategoriesLink.category_id'=>$this->params['named']['category']));
} else {
  $data = $this->paginate('Link', array('Link.status_id'=>'1'));
}

$this->set('links', $data);
```

This is how I did it when I was trying to paginate my `Link` model by a related field. This was with Cake1.2 though, but I think the principle is the same.

I would also recommend installing DebugKit, http://www.ohloh.net/p/cakephp-debugkit , then tinker with the links and conditions until you get a query which works for you.

Sorry, not very technical ;) I'm sure someone can give you a more accurate answer.

PS, Having just reread the question, do you not have these Models linked already? Surely hooking them up in the Models through CakePHP relationships, you'd not need to bind the models and could just use `Containable` or `unbindModel()`

Comment: Thanks, and yes I would like to make the connections between the models permanent, but I tried for hours to make that happen. Fruitlessly. The only way I could link models was to do it dynamically.